# Getting error while connecting to MSSQL with AWS RDS

Tags: amazon-rds

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLJ2b.png) `here is the error . I want to ask While connecting SQL server Authentication I have to used Username and password that i used in while make database in AWS RDS or that i save for SQL Server Authentication but both of them giving same error.`

If anyone has faced the same issue please suggest the solution.

Answer (score 1):

That is a network related issue and not a login issue. The RDS/SQLSERVER instance can't be found using the given endpoint and/or port. You can verify this by using the PowerShell command below or similialy by using Telnet.

```
Test-NetConnection -Port 1433 -ComputerName my-use1-sqlserver-se-instance.xxxxxxx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
```

Simply replace the -ComputerName with your endpoint name. If you are on a non-standard port, then that will also need to be updated.